# Maximize chrome window in QAF

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, bdd, qaf

I am using this code,

`new WebDriverTestBase().getDriver().get("http://www.google.com/");`

But this doesn't launch the chrome in full screen. How to maximize the chrome window in QAF?

Answer (score 1):

To maximize web window,

```
getDriver().manage().window().maximize();
```

or

```
getDriver().manage().window().fullscreen();
```

or

```
getDriver().manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(width, height));
```

Comment: could you tell me how to enter URL of the site in the same piece of code

Comment: It is already in your code, getDriver().get("http://www.google.com/"). Initialize driver, then maximize window and then launch URL. hope it is clear.

Answer (score 1):

For chrome you can try using [chromeOptions capability](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/capabilities)

```
chrome.additional.capabilities={"chromeOptions":{"args":["--start-maximized"]}}
```

Above solution is chrome browser specific. In order for solution to work with different browsers, you also can implement [driver listener](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/qaf_listeners.html#webdriver-listener) and maximize window on driver initialize. For example, your listener method can look like below:

```
package com.sample;
....

public class WindowMaximizeListener extends QAFWebDriverCommandAdapter {
   @Override
   public void onInitialize(QAFExtendedWebDriver driver){
     //write code to maximize browser window
     driver.manage().window().maximize();
   }
}
```

Register listener using `qaf.listeners` property.

```
qaf.listeners=com.sample.WindowMaximizeListener
```

Above listener will maximize browser window as and when new browser session created.